# Processor Core usage with Multi threading with producer consumer in .net platform

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, producer-consumer

So I have a concurrent queue and 2 threads.  I have 1 thread that is going through data and queuing.  I have another thread which is dequeuing the information and performing some actions as a result.

Is is possible that these two threads operate [obviously one cannot guarantee what will run where] on separate cores?  I am using asp.net [MVC] 4.0, I am not in a web garden setup which is why I wonder if it is all constrained to 1 core just like the worker process.  The idea is I have a multi core system and I'd like to be able to utilize this.  I'd use web garden but my queue is in a static class and I think it won't share amongst the worker processes in a web garden.

I was also considering doing a Parallel.ForEach in one of the threads as it may have to perform up to 240 operations which could work in parallel.  Again will this be tied to the worker process core it will it run on other available cores?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will use the other Cores just fine. But m-threading in ASP.NET has other challenges, like under which process and how to keep that alive.

Answer (score 0):

In most multi-core systems, a thread running in a process can jump around to the different cores.  The .NET `Process` class has a writable `ProcessorAffinity` property that allows you to set a bitwise mask to will run threads in a specific process on specific processors.

That being said - is there any reason you can't just let the TPL do it's job?  Your question eludes this, but it is setup to do this kind of work and does a pretty good job at it right out of the box (e.g., your `Parallel.ForEach`).  You do have some control over the granularity with `MaxDegreesOfParallelism`, which limits the number of concurrent operations to that particular instance.

On top of that, have you just considered running it to see if this is an actual problem?